# Are there practical applications to the new prime pair proof?

Tags: cryptography, number-theory

I've [recently heard](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkMXdShDdtY) that its been proven that the set of prime pairs that are separated by no more than 70,000,000 is infinite.

Does this have any impact on cryptography or another practical application?

Comment: @JonasMeyer I think I follow. I've also edited the question to fit what I think the proof is saying.

Comment: Note to readers: Michael Hardy's answer (as it currently stands) is based on how the question appeared for its first hour or so, where Zhang's recent result on prime gaps was incorrectly paraphrased. @Pureferret: I deleted my first comment because it was obsolete, then my second comment because it didn't make much sense without the first.

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10584/what-are-the-possible-cryptographic-implications-of-zhangs-proof-of-the-twin-pr

Comment: You should ask yourself if there is any practical application for a hypothetical proof of **the actual twin-prime** conjecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The twin prime conjecture (and the weaker form of Zhang's theorem) doesn't have (known) connections to any problem in cryptography. So the answer is no, for now. Not every problem connected to prime numbers have necessary an implication to cryptography.

At the moment (like other problems in number theory, for example the Goldbach's conjecture) there is no important practical applications in other sector of mathematics or other disciplines. But nothing prohibit that a day someone find an useful application.

Comment: I'm guessing this holds true for the other half of the question? *Does this have any impact on cryptography or **another practical application?***

Answer (score 3):

What you say you recently heard is false. [I see you've edited the question in light of my answer, so now it says something that is actually true.] There are indeed pairs of primes separated by more than 70 million composite numbers.  What was proved is that there are infinitely many pairs of primes separated by no more than 70 million composite numbers.  The fact that it's true in infinitely many cases does not mean it's true in all cases.  For example, it is conjectured that there are infinitely many twin primes, i.e. primes separated by exactly $2$, so just one composite number is between them.  But if so, that obviously doesn't mean that EVERY pair of consecutive primes is separated by only two.

Comment: Impact on cryptography or any other application? It is obvious that difference between two primes can be arbitrarily large(example, take 2 and the largest discovered prime), I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: @Leolinus : Why should I discuss the "impact on cryptography" of a statement that is NOT TRUE?  The point of my answer was to explain the mistake.

Comment: I guess the question is pretty obvious, the person who asked it did a quick misinterpretation and one can definitely edit the question to its right form.

It is definitely interesting as it touches the Goldbach conjecture and, I guess, Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: Fixing a mistake of that kind is not off topic for this forum, and people who are confused about a point like that would do well to remedy that problem before doing a lot of other things.  If we were talking about a typo or the like, I'd agree with you because that's not a misunderstanding of math, and math is our topic here.  Certainly the other question is also on topic, but a answer that answers only part of what's posted is often of some value.

Comment: Ok, so I've fixed my question (I think) can you update your answer?